# To get site-specific email settings

Tags: feature-request, email-notification

Sometimes, I want to concentrate on one topic and would like not have emails from my old questions in some Stackexchange sites so regularly.
It would be good if you send notifications about one site once a week and another site every 3 hours. 
So more customisation for the email settings is wanted.

**Is there any way to get smarter email settings?**

Comment: Hmmm... not sure how useful it might be here, but it's an interesting idea. I know that on some sites I do very much appreciate being able to choose options like weekly digests.